# Air 2.6 iOS - cannot install on Device

Tags: iphone, ios, air, adt

I am struggling to get an Air app installed on my iPod. If I follow this tutorial:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f3cb56e2a12cc36970aa-8000.html

I get the error

> The app "Hello World iOS" was not installed on the iPod "Davids iPod" because it is not compatible with this iPod"

I have no problem if I use packager for iPhone, with the same certificates etc.

Does anybody know what might be the problem?

**It turned out my device is not supported - see my answer below**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just found:

Supported iOS devices
As part of supporting the latest and most powerful Flash runtime features on iOS, we have chosen to drop support for the original iPhone and the iPhone 3G, along with iPhone OS 3. AIR 2.6 supports building apps for the following iOS 4 devices:

- iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4
- iPod Touch (3rd Generation and 4th Generation)
- iPad

source: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/whats-new-in-air-26.html

Im developing for 2nd Gen Ipod Touch +

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the minimum SDK required for that app? WHich Xcode Version are you using? Xcode4 doesnt even show connected devieces that do not have th eminimum SDK installed. As far as I rememeber in the previous xCode versions you have to adjust the minimum SDK for which the app can be installed

Comment: I just found that the air rumtime doesn't support 2nd gen Ipods. thanks though.